# Autowiring using @Autowired setter giving NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, annotations, autowired

I am very new bie in spring. I am start learning Autowiring using @Autowired setter method. I have created a small app and tried to run and got null pointer exception:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at com.develop.Tiger.toString(Tiger.java:29) 
at com.develop.Test.main(Test.java:16)**

I implement the app as below

**Color.java**

```
package com.develop;
public class Color {    
    private String baseColor;   
    private String textureColor;

    public String getBaseColor() {
        return baseColor;
    }
    public void setBaseColor(String baseColor) {
        this.baseColor = baseColor;
    }
    public String getTextureColor() {
        return textureColor;
    }
    public void setTextureColor(String textureColor) {
        this.textureColor = textureColor;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return baseColor + " base skin color and " + textureColor + " texture color." ;

    }
}
```

**Tiger.java**

```
package com.develop;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
public class Tiger {

    private String name;
    private Color colorBean;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Color getColorBean() {
        return colorBean;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setColorBean(Color color) {
        this.colorBean= color;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "The " + name + " has " + colorBean.toString();

    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
package com.develop;    
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");  
        BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(resource);         

        //AutoWire By @annotation
        Tiger tiger = (Tiger) factory.getBean("tigerBean");
        System.out.println(tiger.toString());
    }

}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd">  

     <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="colorBean" class="com.develop.Color">
        <property name="baseColor" value="white" />
        <property name="textureColor" value="grey" />
    </bean>


      <!-- Auto-Wiring with @Autowired annotation -->
      <bean id="tigerBean" class="com.develop.Tiger">
        <property name="name" value="tiger" />
     </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: why package name in `applicationcontext.xml` and actual classes `(Tiger,Color)` is different?

Comment: The qualified class names "com.cfdevshop.Color" and "com.cfdevshop.Tiger" in the applicationContext.xml are not consistent with the package "com.develop" that contains the java classes Color and Tiger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Test.java in

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:applicationContext.xml");  

        //AutoWire By @annotation
        Tiger tiger = (Tiger) context.getBean("tigerBean");
        System.out.println(tiger.toString());
    }

}
```

This is the output

> The tiger has white base skin color and grey texture color.